# What is the file extension for things in the /bin folder?

Tags: command-line, file-format

I was looking at stuff like /bin/bash, and I wanted to make my own file like that that's full of aliases, but I need to know the file extension. Please tell me.

Comment: Linux does not use file extensions like Windows, just get the command spelled right.

Comment: You want to use BASH aliases?

Comment: By "file extension", do you mean the file's [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type)?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add stuff in /bin as this directory is handled by the OS. Use a custom directory in your homedir or /opt/monkeyman/bin for example, and use an extension only if you find it useful for some reason. Unix/Linux doesn't require or even make use of a file extension for commands, it only wants an executable to have the executable permission set.